# Moving Records from one db to another and tracking new identity columns

Tags: sql-server-2000, etl

I have 2 sql server 2000 databases with identical schemas.

I have to move a subset of rows from a given table from Database A to Database B.
I also have to move all related rows from other tables over to Database B as well.

Here is a simplified example

Let's Assume in each DB there there are the following tables:
      Authors, Books, Awards, Sales.

Let's say that each of these tables has an identity column which is the PK. These columns are named AuthorID, BookID, AwardID, SaleID.

I need to move "Stephen King" from the Authors table in Database A to Database B.
Let's say the Stephen King record in Database A has an AuthorID of 12. I also have to move over all the rows in the Books tabel with a FK AuthorID of 12. Same with the awards and sales tables.

I've written code earlier when Database B was brand new to handle this using the "SET IDENTITY_INSERT" command. So Stephen King ended up with the same AuthorID in each table.

The problem now is the staff has been busy adding new records to Database B, and I can't simply migrate records from database A to database B without running into PK conflict. I have no choice but to let Database B assign new PK values to the migrated records and keep track of them so when the related records come over, the proper FK is used.

In this simplified example, I have 4 tables that I have to code for.

In my real life example I have 46 tables.

I'm not looking forward to coding this by hand.

Is there any preexisting tools that I can purchase to make this process easier?

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to change all of your PKs and FKs in your source database to be negative numbers. Then you can INSERT them into the new db with no collisions.

Comment: Interesting idea. But I'm not sure how the front end would behave if it came around a PK with a negative value.

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify a completely different set of fields on the table that you can create a unique constraint against that you can enforce on both systems, then you can use that also to compare the two systems to ensure the data is the same. Without a way to uniquely identify the data between the two systems, there's not going to be any functional way to migrate data between them.